# Header Template Image during Cron

Tags: magento-2.1, luma-theme

when my Cron got executed I am getting Luma image as Header Image in Email instead of my custom Image. When I write the same functionality as API i am getting the right Image. Can some one help me on this?

Comment: In all emails or any particular email ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload transaction email logo on below path.

> Content -> Design -> Configuration -> Select Your Theme -> Transaction Email -> Logo Image
>
> [image: Path]

Comment: I added the Image. Even though it is taking Luma Image

Comment: clear cache, static content deploy and try again

Comment: I did, but still coming as Luma Image.
FYI: Image I required is getting when I run the Cron functionality as API.

Comment: This is not working.